# How to Access the keycodes of special charecters in firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

We are performing front end validations by checking the keycodes of the user input. This approach is successful in chrome and Internet Explorer,but we are unable to access the keycodes in firefox browser.

```
function alphanumeric_only(e)
{
var keycode;
if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
else if (event) keycode = event.keyCode;
else if (e) keycode = e.which;
else return true;
if(
(keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57) || (keycode >= 65 && keycode <= 90) || (keycode >= 97 && keycode <= 122) || (keycode == 35) || (keycode == 32) || (keycode == 44) || (keycode == 45) || (keycode == 95))
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
return true;
}`
```

We are invoking that function from input field as follows.....

```
<div style="float: left;">
   <input type="text" id="customname" onkeypress="return alphanumeric_only(this);" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: try one of these: `event.key, event.charCode, event.event.key, event.metaKey` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Comment: I have tried with all those options, getting the keycode as undefined in firefox.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello You can try this code it's working all the browser :)

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<div style="float: left;">
   <input type="text" id="customname" onkeypress="alphanumeric_only(event)" value="">
</div>

<script>
function alphanumeric_only(event)
{
  var keycode1 = event.which || event.keyCode;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The Unicode value is: " + keycode1 ;  
  if((keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57) || (keycode >= 65 && keycode <= 90) ||    (keycode >= 97 && keycode <= 122) || (keycode == 35) || (keycode == 32) || (keycode == 44) || (keycode == 45) || (keycode == 95))
  {
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're expicitly passing `this` as the argument to the function, not the event

```
onkeypress="return alphanumeric_only(this);"
```

which means `e` in the function is the element, not the event

```
function alphanumeric_only(e) {

    // "e" is the element. not the event
```

This still works in Chrome and IE because those browsers support the global `window.event`, but Firefox does not.

The solution is to pass the event as well

```
onkeypress="return alphanumeric_only(event, this);"
```

and

```
function alphanumeric_only(e, element) { ...
```

or even better, remove the inline javascript

```
<input type="text" id="customname" value="">
```

and use a proper event handler that makes this a lot easier

```
document.getElementById('customname').addEventListener('keypress', function(evt) {
    var keycode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;

    if ((keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57) || 
        (keycode >= 65 && keycode <= 90) || 
        (keycode >= 97 && keycode <= 122) || 
        (keycode == 35) || (keycode == 32) || 
        (keycode == 44) || (keycode == 45) || 
        (keycode == 95)) {

        e.preventDefault();

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for brief explanation...I have passed "event" instead of "this" as an argument. Its working fine...